# The most non-reflective surface

Tags: materials, light

I am developing a moonbase and I am looking for **dramatic contrast** in the light. Inside the base, I want rooms that are normally lit with a door frame and the next room absolute dark.
What surface would be the best for the dark rooms? I am looking for surfaces with a **dark matte** aspect.
Thanks

Comment: Although you can use a strange material to achieve it, I would personally recommend using *color management* with *exposure* and *gamma*. This method can produce a more realistic render if the setting is well tuned.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have absolutely no light interacts with the surface, just unplug everything from the material output node.

For a Lambertian surface rather than a completely flat one, you could use a Diffuse shader set to completely black.

If you wanted it have a combination, you could mix the Diffuse with just... nothing... and then adjust mix factor to control the blending.

Answer (score 2):

### A Material Output Node with no connected sockets

No light can escape the surface.

[image: disconnected Material Output node]

Not very realistic unless you're rendering a black hole. But you did ask for *the most* non-reflective surface. ;-)

<sub>Material using disconnected sockets - the black circle is completely unaffected by the light source (sphere)</sub>

[image: Pure black surface created using a disconnected Material Output Node]

-or-

### A black Emission Shader

[image: Completely black emission shader]

This has the same effect as a disconnected Material Output Node - no light reflects from it because this shader is strictly for emission. When the color is *completely* black, there is nothing to emit.

Answer (score 0):

A diffuse shader with the color set to pitch black should do the trick. As it is a purely diffuse surface it will not reflect any light and therefore the inside of the rooms will appear to be pitch black.

[image: Diffuse shader]

Alternatively, shade the surfaces of the rooms normally and place a light source inside them with a negative emission value to subtract light from them.

Comment: Negative light sources might not be the best idea. They will introduce a lot of noise and all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using Toon specular reflection if using Blender Internal.

You can also try setting the material completely shadeless, or using a **diffuse** and **black emission node** both connected to a **mix node** to get some slight black emission.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help, but for flat black or white textures I just plug an *Invert Node* into the material output, no shader nodes needed.